# reusing TableCellEditor objects

Tags: java, swing, tablecelleditor

So I have lots of tables and lots of cell editors, with lots of stuff in them.  I figured I should be reusing them, not doing new() every time since the whole thing is set getTableCellEditorComponent() but still, nearly every time I try to do it, I get "leftovers" in old cells, and other oddities.  I can usually correct the problem by just making a new one every time, but is this bad?

Thanks!
Joshua

Answer (score 1):

`JTable`s are huge. While the `JComponent` subclass in a `TableCellEditor` may also be quite large, it isn't really worth worrying about. Further, it is a good idea to avoid sharing mutable objects, particularly ones as complicated as Swing components. Having one parent per component lifetime seems a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is always zero or one editor per `JTable`, the performance of the `getTableCellEditorComponent()` call is not extremely critical. Creating new components must be avoided when dealing with the table renderer, though.